# Problems using CruiseControl.Net API : project not found

Tags: api, cruisecontrol.net, remoting

I am trying to retrieve Build Projects related information from my CruiseControl server through command line using cccmd.exe and passing the url and project name as command line arguments. The problem is when I am trying to use API's exposed by Cruise Control Service like

```
client.GetArtifactDirectory(project.Name);
client.GetLatestBuildName(project.Name);
```

I am getting the exception "The project does not exists on the CCNet Server" for my local CCNet Server.

For my production build server, I am getting the exception "Key cannot be null".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an API for Cruise Control .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467364/is-there-an-api-for-cruise-control-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, had to copy the folders and foldername.state files that are created during project build process to the directory from where ccservice.exe was running.